# How to authenticate user with firebase sdk

Tags: codeigniter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using this [SDK](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/master/docs/authentication.rst) and following this [documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html). Now I am trying to create and authenticate user in firebase db. How can I do that.I am doing the project in Codeigniter and in my controller I did this:

```
    public function register()
    {
    $firebase = (new Firebase\Factory())->create();

    $tokenHandler = $firebase->getTokenHandler();

    $uid = 'a-uid';
    $claims = ['foo' => 'bar']; // optional

    // Returns a Lcobucci\JWT\Token instance
    $customToken = $tokenHandler->createCustomToken($uid, $claims);
    echo $customToken; // "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1..."

    $idTokenString = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1...';
    // Returns a Lcobucci\JWT\Token instance
    $idToken = $tokenHandler->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);

    $uid = $idToken->getClaim('sub');

    echo $uid; // 'a-uid'
    }
```

and I call the function It gave me this error:

```
    Type: Kreait\Firebase\Exception\ServiceAccountDiscoveryFailed
    Message: Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount\Discovery\FromEnvironmentVariable: The environment variable "FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS" is not set. Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount\Discovery\FromEnvironmentVariable: The environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" is not set. Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount\Discovery\FromGoogleWellKnownFile: The well known file is not readable or invalid

  Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\firebasedb\vendor\kreait\firebase-
  php\src\Firebase\ServiceAccount\Discoverer.php

  Line Number: 48
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Any kind of help are appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Okay I solve this problem with default .json file path like this:

```
  $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(JSON_FILE_PATH.'google-service-account.json');
  $firebase = (new Factory)
  ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
  ->create();
```

Now can I register a new user from web-app? Can anyone Help please. I have been stopped in this problem since long. Helps are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You Set JSON Key environment variables* 
**FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS** **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** ?

> try reading this [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP Setup](http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#setup)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. Now can you see my edit, Please.

Comment: You yet error traditional ? after insert FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Comment: there's no error, i am asking how can i Create new user in firebase?

Comment: you run project at firebase-hosting ?

Comment: I have the same question. The link in the accepted answer does not explain or give an example of how to create the FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS environmental variable, it only says to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#authenticate-with-admin-privileges

There two crucial points to note.

1. Many use cases for verifying ID tokens on the server can be accomplished by using Security Rules for the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Storage. See if those solve your problem before verifying ID tokens yourself.
2. The ID token verification methods included in the **Firebase Admin SDKs are meant to verify ID tokens that come from the client SDKs, not the custom tokens that you create with the Admin SDKs** Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users/#auth_tokens

---

About Users:
From https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html
You have a sample

```
$request = \Kreait\Auth\Request\CreateUser::new()
->withUnverifiedEmail('user@example.com')
->withPhoneNumber('+15555550100')
->withClearTextPassword('secretPassword')
->withDisplayName('John Doe')
->withPhotoUrl('http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png');
$createdUser = $auth->createUser($request);
```

Please Note:

> By default, Firebase Authentication will generate a random uid for the new user. If you instead want to specify your own uid for the new user, you can include in the properties passed to the user creation method:

```
$properties = [
        'uid' => 'some-uid',
            // other properties
    ];
    $request = \Kreait\Auth\Request\CreateUser::new()
            ->withUid('some-uid')
    // with other properties
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with **Laravel** in my case, here is the solution:

First save the `.json` credentials file you got from Firebase project into the root of your Laravel app on the same level as `.env` file.

The `json` file looks like `you-file-firebase-adminsdk-0000-9845985498a.json`

Then open the `.env` file and create a new environment variable and paste the `json` credential file name.

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=../you-file-firebase-adminsdk-0000-9845985498a.json
```